# Send right click event to an element in an iframe in an internet explorer 8 document

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, autohotkey

I need to learn how to right click on an element in a webpage using IE8 document mode.

The webpage I am working with is PTC's windchill 10, which I believe is created usings sencha's extjs. I am not sure if extjs registers the .click() method as a click always. Some elements I need to use onmousedown and onmouseup to get a click to work.

This function I have tested on the iframe object psbIFrame to do a regular .click() and it works using autohotkey.

Autohotkey Syntax

```
click_event:=window_handle.document.all.psbIFrame.contentWindow.document.createEventObject()
click_event.button:=1 ;left button down
links[a_index-1].fireEvent("onclick", click_event)
```

Javascript Type Syntax

```
document.all.psbIFrame.contentWindow.document.createEventObject();
click_event.button=1;
links[a_index-1].fireEvent("onclick", click_event)
```

I also have this working for other elements not in an iframe.

```
event:=document.createEventObject()
event.button:=1 ;left button down
element.fireEvent("onmousedown", event)
element.fireEvent("onmouseup", event)
```

Those are all left clicks since the document mode is ie8. When I set the button to 2 and do either of those I don't get anything happening.

Does anyone else have access to a windchill page that can help me test?

Comment: Don't think I can help, but I give you my +1 for a good question.

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem. What are you trying to achieve? Source code of the web page would help certainly. Also, you could post some screenshots.

Comment: Hi Guys. I think I answered my own question. The event for a right click to get a menu popup is oncontextmenu. Some of the other times my click wasn't working I just needed to reget the iwebbrowser interface pointer and it refreshed the dom enough to have the element click properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.fireEvent("oncontextmenu")
```

This does what I expect a right click to do. With fireEvent you don't even need to initialize the event most times it seems. FireEvent will do that in the background assuming some defaults. I don't know if what I was doing in my question with changing the button to 2 even makes sense.
http://help.dottoro.com/ljvtddtm.php for fireEvent
http://help.dottoro.com/lagstsiq.php/#MouseEvent_Members for a list of mouse events